# How to start fragment from a specific position and be able to go to previous positions?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a listView. When I click on an element of the listView I pass 2 string arrays and the list position. I use this information to start a pager of fragments. Everything is working fine. I get the information, everything is displayed. Let's say I click on listItem-5, the new fragment will start at 5 and I'll be able to go to 6,7,8 etc., but I won't be able to go left at 4,3,2,1.How can I achieve this ?

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager_fragment);
        ArrayList<String> email=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("email");
        ArrayList<String> about=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("about");
        int listPosition = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");


        ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),email,about,listPosition);
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    }

    private SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    // Extend from SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter now instead for more dynamic ViewPager items
    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final ArrayList<String> email;
        private final ArrayList<String> about;
        private int listPosition;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,ArrayList<String> email,ArrayList<String> about,int lPosition) {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.email=email;
            this.about = about;
            listPosition = lPosition;
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return email.size();
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(email.get(listPosition+position), about.get(listPosition+position));
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you cant just make a sublist and pass it to your adapter?

Comment: this.email = email.sublist(listPosition, email.size()); this.about = about.sublist(listPosition, about.size());

Comment: and how is that going to let me swipe right ?

Comment: Your, for example, fifth element becomes first, all next elements will exists and you will be able to swipe right.

Comment: I don't understand. Now I'm able to see all the elements but not in the right order. I still can swipe left and see all the elements. I just want to be able to see them properly. If I'm at item 5 and want to go to 4 swipe right, if I want to go to 6 swipe right. And they should end at the last/first item.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understanding the code design. Allow me to understand your sample scenario. If you click on listItem-5, perhaps you used code:

```
adapterViewPager.getItem(0);
```

If you need to see **fragment 4**, you need to go backwards. Hence use code:

```
adapterViewPager.getItem(-1);
```

Otherwise, use code:

```
adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),email,about, 0);
```

Note the **value 0** for the 4th parameter to start from the **first fragment**.

Comment: I want to start at a specific position, and from that position to swipe left or right depending on how many item are before and after the position that I clicked on

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem with code passing value 0 to the fourth parameter, as said above?  I think the issue for me understanding is that I don't see the full code related to your issue.

Comment: I have a listView. When you click on an element it starts the activity which starts the fragment. Before starting that activity it passes those values(ArrayList email, ArrayLIst about and the int listPosition). In the activity the fragment opened should be the one at that particular listPosition.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel, Actually I understand that part of the code design. However if you start with listPosition of 5, you are more/less committed to that starting position. This is the part I don't agree with the design. With that said, what's the problem with code adapterViewPager.getItem(-1)? You can call this method when user swipes to the left.

Comment: I solved it. I just had to set viewPager.setCurrentItem(listPosition);

Comment: @BogdanDaniel, Ah yes...you used the opposite method of getItem, another way of looking the same problem with a different eye. Congratulations!